# How do I start a subprocess which runs in the background until it is told to terminate gracefully?

Tags: python, concurrency

From within my python script, I want to start another python script which will run in the background waiting for the instruction to terminate.

1. Host Python script (H1) starts subprocess P1.
2. P1 performs some short lived work & returns a sentinel to indicate that it is now going to sleep awaiting instructions to terminate.
3. H1 polls for this sentinel repeatedly. When it receives the sentinel, it performs some other IO bound task and when that completes, tells P1 to die gracefully (meaning close any resources that you have acquired).

Is this feasible to do with the **subprocess** module ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to do it with `multiprocessing` module, or even `threading` module?  It is certainly possible with a separate call to the python interpreter using `subprocess` module, but you might be over-complicating things a bit.

Comment: Yes, I have a hunch that I am over-complicating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"""H1"""
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import sys

def P1(conn):
    print 'P1: some short lived work'
    sys.stdout.flush()
    conn.send('work done')
    # wait for shutdown command...
    conn.recv()
    conn.close()
    print 'P1: shutting down'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=P1, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    print parent_conn.recv()
    print 'H1: some other IO bound task'
    parent_conn.send("game over")
    p.join()
```

Output:

```
P1: some short lived work
work done
H1: some other IO bound task
P1: shutting down
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, start the process with :

```
p=subprocess.Popen([list for the script to execute], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You can then read from `p.stdout` and `p.stderr` to watch for your sentinel and write to `p.stdin` to send messages to the child process.  If you are running on a posix system, you might consider using pexpect instead; it doesn't support MS Windows, but it handles communicating with child processes better than subprocess.